Restrict Fourier Transform to a Hypersurface
Assume a field evolves according to the Klein-Gordon equation
$$(\Box+m^2)\phi=0$$
The general solution to this is given by Fourier mode decomposition
$$\phi(t,\vec{x})=\int\frac{\text{d}^3p}{(2\pi)^3}\tilde{\phi}(\vec{p})e^{i(\omega_{\vec{p}}t-\vec{p}\vec{x})}$$
where the complex conjugate/2nd solution to form a complete basis is omitted. We can understand $\phi(t,\vec{x})$ as a function taking $4$ spacetime components, restricting it to a hypersurface $$\Sigma_t=\{x^\mu\in\mathbb{R}^{1,3}\vert x^0\equiv t=\text{const}\}$$. Given the initial data on such a hypersurface, we find the mode decomposition by inverting the Fourier transform,
$$\tilde{\phi}(\vec{p})e^{-i\omega_{\vec{p}}t}=\int_{\Sigma_t}\text{d}^3x\phi(t,\vec{x})e^{i\vec{p}\vec{x}}$$
These two prescriptions explicitly capture both directions of the bijective mapping
$$\phi(t,\vec{x})\equiv\phi(x^\mu\in\Sigma_t)\leftrightarrow\tilde{\phi}(\vec{p})$$
Now the question:
Is it possible to find $\tilde{\phi}(\vec{p})$ from the data on any other hypersurface, that is $\phi(x^\mu\in\Sigma)$ where $\Sigma$ is not necessarily a slice of constant time $t$? The mapping $\tilde{\phi}(\vec{p})\mapsto\phi(x^\mu\in\Sigma)$ is trivially given by the same formula as above, just putting different values of $x^\mu$. The inverse map $\phi(x^\mu\in\Sigma)\mapsto\tilde{\phi}(\vec{p})$ is what I am interested in.
